# How does the "plumbing" of real-time (node/socket.io) work?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, socket.io, real-time, instagram

I'm currently building a real-time web application that utilizes the MEAN stack (Mongo,Express,Angular,Node). My question relates to how Node (and more specifically Socket.io) work in a real-time app which makes calls to an API (in this case Instagram).

I'm subscribing to several locations (lat/lon coordinates) with the Instagram API. I want my web app to automatically add photos as they are taken (and geo-tagged) around these locations.

How I THINK this will work:

- Subscribe to several locations through the Instagram API
- Instagram sends me a GET request to my callback URL when data at API endpoint changes
- Fire off a GET request TO Instagram in response, based on which endpoint changed
- Save the new photo(s) to Mongo database using my own API
- Emit an event from server to client using Socket.io, containing new photo(s) data
- 'Capture' this event with a Socket.io listener on client side and display new photo(s)

Does this seem reasonable at a detailed level or am I missing (even some tiny) steps?

Answer (score 1):

1. Emit an event from server to client using Socket.io
2. 'Capture' this event with a Socket.io listener on client side
3. Fire off a GET request to my API to pull the new photo(s) from Mongo database

This can be reduced to a single step:

1. Emit an event from server and send the photo as data-uri.

You may need to watch out for the amount of data that can be sent via sockets.

Comment: I have the database steps beacuse I want the photo stream to pull from my database. Basically I want the user to be able to continue scrolling down to see older photos. The good news as far as "amount of data" is concerned is that I'm only sending (via sockets), and saving, references to the photo location on Instagram. I'm not saving or sending the actual image.